# how to delete my database in a simple way

Tags: mysql

I want to delete my database used in my webhotel. How do I do?
I am a newbie, and have tried to find a way to do it, but without success.
Please assist me.
Reason is, I want to start all over.
Best regards, dolle

Comment: If your web host offers a MySQL control panel, it may have a database management utility. Otherwise, executing the query `DROP DATABASE <databasename>` is all you need, provided the connected user is allowed to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP database_name
```

If your database name is *webhotel_db*, you can run this command in your database client's query box:

```
DROP webhotel_db
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete your databases or tables from phpMyAdmin by using **DROP**.

There are two kinds of DROP buttons. You should select the appropriate one for your purpose.

## 1. Delete database:

phpMyAdmin **>** Click on the database you wish to delete (on the left of your screen) **>** Click on the **DROP tab**

[Click to watch an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcJzJ5bSeU)

## 2. Delete tables:

phpMyAdmin **>** Click on the database (on the left of your screen) **>** check the table and click **DROP** (you can find this DROP button on the same line as your table)

[Click to watch an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTnV4VmJWPk)